Using Python to identify Map objects used in Esri ArcGIS Enterprise Portal or AGOL Web Applications?
I'm trying to list the feature layers shown in each map from every web application, dashboard, and storymap on my Enterprise Portal.
Is there a way to retrieve all the map objects that belong to an app perhaps something like this?
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.mapping import WebMap

gis = GIS(url="https://myesriportal.org/portal", username="admin", password="PASSWORD")
webapp_items = gis.content.search(query="type:Web Mapping Application", max_items=10000)
webapp_items += gis.content.search(query="type:Dashboard", max_items=10000)
webapp_items += gis.content.search(query="type:StoryMap", max_items=10000)

#print the web app title, web map title, and layer name
for webapp_item in webapp_items:
    for webmap_item in webapp_item.content.webmaps: # Does something like this exist?
        webmap_obj = WebMap(webmap_item)
        for layer in webmap_obj:
            print(webapp_item.title, webmap_item.title, layer.title)‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍


Check out the "datasources" property in the api reference. https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.apps.expbuilder.html#webexperience
